# Connected Plane of integers

Tags: general-topology, integers

I am curious about the plane of integers, that is $(x,y)$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is there any way to prove it is not connected or connected? How would one go about it? I feel that $\mathbb{Z}^2$ should not be connected due to the "gaps" between ecah number.

Comment: "Connected" has no meaning until you define a topology on the set. Under the topology inherited from ${\bf R}^2$, your plane is certainly not connected.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to write it I have included it, is it due to it acquiring the subspace topology?

Comment: The subspace topology is what I mean by "the topology inherited from ${\bf R}^2$.

Comment: Thought so and if I recall correctly the subspace topology here is discrete if I recall correctly right?

Comment: @Zelos: Yes, it is. And a space with the discrete topology and at least two points is not connected.